# why we can not add members to Teams channels which have auto-pin set to On or Off

Tags: microsoft-teams

we have 7 channels for a Teams:-

[image]

but for 6 Teams the Add members button is grey out as follow:-

[image]

so why we can not add members to Teams channels which have auto-pin set to On or Off. we can only add members to channels which have their auto-pin set to Empty??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Six of the channels are standard channels. This means everyone on the team has access to those channels by default by being a member of the Team.

One of the channels allows you to add members because it is a private channel e.g. you have to choose who is going to be a member of a private channel.

Comment: ok thanks for the info,, but i have noted that standard channels do not have sharepoint sites,, is this the case always?

Comment: Standard channels have folders in the Team's SharePoint site. Only private channels have their own SharePoint site.